Google RE2 escape
I am trying in Google Sheet to
to extract the link only from following cell content:
href="/england/nekko-ltd">
I use =REGEXEXTRACT(B4, "href=\"([^"])\"") -- This give error.
It seems RE2 does not like: \" how do I escape the double quotation mark?
Thanks

Use code fences to format your code. Test formatting before posting questions.
